# Limit of the sequence which depends on another sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

[image]
Can anyone solve this problem ?

I could not find any relation between terms of sequence. 
So what is nth term of bn ? Can we evaluate an without finding bn ? Please help

Comment: inform yourself about the Fibonacci numbers ;)

Comment: Are you familiar with solving linear recursion equations? The sequence $(b_n)$ can be found explicitly with a standard method resembling the solution process of a second order ODE with constant coefficients.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.